# Сортировка опций в админке Opencart 2

Tags: opencart

Как задать в админке  чтоб сортировка  значений опции была по порядку добавления этих опций к товару, а не по порядку сортировке в самой опции?

Answer (score 0):

Оставляйте порядок сортировки каждого значения опции равным 0. Тогда в карте товара они будут отображаться  в порядке добавления к товару.